# Writing Firefox Extension with C++ code

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, npapi, firebreath, browser-plugin

I currently have a Firefox extension/plugin combo that works well, and was written with a combination of NPAPI (Firebreath) C++ code and Javascript.  The extension works by defining a browser overlay (overlay.xul/overlay.js) that is loaded on every webpage via a script src="overlay.js" tag.

I need to adapt it for the upcoming changes for Firefox Webextensions and deprecation of XPCOM/XUL.

From what I understand, Webextensions will be primarily Javascript based.  How would I be able to continue using the C++ portion of my extension?  Note that porting the C++ NPAPI library to Javascript would be a non-starter for various reasons.

Comment: I'm not sure about Webextensions but you can move to js-ctypes https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [Native messaging](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Native_messaging) to keep some part of your code in C++.

Be aware only the background script can directly communicate with your native/C++ code. But these messages can later be dispatched to your content scripts.

The communication between your C++ code and the background script is through the `stdin`/`stdout`.

There is a nice example between python script and web-extension on github: https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/tree/master/native-messaging